# How to i filter my array with a combobox and search button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an array that gives teachers information. And I have a list component that lists these teachers. I want to a combobox and filter for this array.

this is my array

```js
private _infoList: Array<AcademicPersonnelInfoModel> = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Prof. Dr.',
    firstName: 'Atakan',
    lastName: 'bir'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Prof. Dr.',
    firstName: 'Atakan',
    lastName: 'iki'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Prof. Dr.',
    firstName: 'Atakan',
    lastName: 'uc'
  },
];
```

this is my .html

```
<div class="col top-bar">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active">


                <input type="text" ng-model=search.accountName>
                <select ng-model="search.id" id="">
                    <option value=''>All</option>
                    <option value=1>1</option>
                    <option value=2>2</option>
                </select>

                <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
                    <tr ng-repeat="account in $data  | filter:search.lastName | filter:search.id">
                        <td data-title="'id'">
                            {{account.account.accountId.id}}
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'lastName'">
                            {{account.account.accountName}}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should i do in typescript to be able to filter this list?

this is my ts file

```
export class AcademicPersonnelListComponent implements OnInit {

/** */


/** */
private _academicPersonelList: Array<AcademicPersonnelInfoModel> = [];
public get academicPersonelList(): Array<AcademicPersonnelInfoModel> {
    return this._academicPersonelList;
}
```

I have an array that gives teachers information. And i have a list component that lists these teachers. I want to a combobox and filter for this array.

Comment: Is this AngularJS? according to ng-repeat ng-model

Comment: no. Angular cli with typescript

Comment: Once you run "ng serve" what error do you receive?

Comment: the `filter` pipe is not supported in angular 2+ like angularJS

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 2+ build in pipes does not support `filter` pipe** like AngularJS. You need to create a [custom pipe](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-pipes-angular/) for filtering to able to do so:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'yourTeacherFilter'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
    // The pipe's transform method take first Argurment is the data using that pipe( which is data before the '|' mark in the template), the others parameter is optional
  transform(input: Array<AcademicPersonnelInfoModel>, lastname, id): number {
    // Your logic of returned values go here
    return input.filter( x => x.id === id && x.lastName.includes(lastname));
  }
}
```

What the above code does is created a **`pipe`** that take an array as the main input along with two additionals paremeter `lastname` and `id`. The pipe do the logic you write inside and will return whatever is returned inside the `transform()` function.

Declare the newly created **`pipe`** into your app.module @NgModule() declarations array then you can apply that pipe to your template:

```
*ngFor= "let account of $data | yourTeacherFilter: search.lastName : search.id"

// The input following `yourTeacherFilter` should match the order
// of parameters you defined inside your custom pipe's transfomrm() function
```

This is just an simple example pipe for filtering data, you will need further logic to enhance the pipe in your app.